# How to achieve an automatic linebreak in tabularx with \multicolumn?

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx, multicolumn

I'm working with `tabularx` and now I'd like to combine all 3 cells of one line to a single one, but my text is quite long and I don't know how to get it to make automatic linebreak in the text in this environment. 
Someone know what I should do?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{1.\linewidth}{|p{.31\linewidth} | p{.31\linewidth} |     p{.31\linewidth} |}
    \hline 
    \textbf{Ernout/Meillet\textsubscript{4}} & \textbf{REW\textsubscript{3}} & \textbf{DÉRom}  \\ 
    \hline 
    apert\={u}ra & ap\u{e}rt\={u}ra & \makecell[l]{*/aper\textquotesingle t-ur-a/\\\hspace{4pt} $\longrightarrow$ I. */aper\textquotesingle t-ur-a/  \\ \hspace{4pt} $\longrightarrow$ II. */oper\textquotesingle t-ur-a/} \\ 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Les issues romanes ont été subdivisées selon les deux types dont elles relèvent : */aper't-ur-a/ (I.) et */oper't-ur-a/ (II.). I. représente une évolution phonétique régulière de protorom. */aper't-ur-a/ et il existe en italien, romanche, espagnol, asturien, galicien et portugais....  }   \\
    \hline 
    \end{tabularx} 
    \end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: sidenote **never use `tabularx` without `X` columns**

Answer (score 6):

Use `X` columns and a `p` column for the last part.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}
\hline 
\textbf{Ernout/Meillet\textsubscript{4}} & \textbf{REW\textsubscript{3}} & \textbf{DÉRom}  \\ 
\hline 
apert\={u}ra & ap\u{e}rt\={u}ra & 
  \makecell[l]{%
    */aper\textquotesingle t-ur-a/\\
    \hspace{4pt} $\longrightarrow$ I. */aper\textquotesingle t-ur-a/ \\
    \hspace{4pt} $\longrightarrow$ II. */oper\textquotesingle t-ur-a/
  } \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{%
  Les issues romanes ont été subdivisées selon les deux types dont elles
  relèvent: */aper't-ur-a/ (I.) et */oper't-ur-a/ (II.). I. représente
  une évolution phonétique régulière de protorom. */aper't-ur-a/ et il
  existe en italien, romanche, espagnol, asturien, galicien et portugais....  } \\
\hline 
\end{tabularx} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What I propose is a cleanup solution. IE:

1. Removed extra spacing from the sides of the table
2. Removed `tabularx` since no X columns are used
3. For the new column I used `@{}m{\textwidth}@{}` in fact:

   a. the `@{}` get rid of the extra spacing

   b. the `\textwidth` gives the breadth needed (tweakable to obtain the best effect)

   c. the `m` specifications allows the cell to hyphenate
4. Got rid of all of the vertical separator because of their ugliness and because they impair readability
5. Used the `booktabs` rules because they are fancier
6. removed extra horizontal lines (at most one can *consider* a `midrule` before the long cell

So here is the code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{.31\linewidth} p{.31\linewidth}  p{.31\linewidth}@{}}
\toprule
    \textbf{Ernout/Meillet\textsubscript{4}} & \textbf{REW\textsubscript{3}} & \textbf{DÉRom}  \\ 
    \midrule 
    apert\={u}ra & ap\u{e}rt\={u}ra & \makecell[l]{*/aper\textquotesingle t-ur-a/\\\hspace{4pt} $\longrightarrow$ I. */aper\textquotesingle t-ur-a/  \\ \hspace{4pt} $\longrightarrow$ II. */oper\textquotesingle t-ur-a/} \\ 

    \multicolumn{3}{@{}m{\textwidth}@{}}{Les issues romanes ont été subdivisées selon les deux types dont elles relèvent : */aper't-ur-a/ (I.) et */oper't-ur-a/ (II.). I. représente une évolution phonétique régulière de protorom. */aper't-ur-a/ et il existe en italien, romanche, espagnol, asturien, galicien et portugais....  }   \\
    \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

And a sample

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `p{\dimexpr0.93\linewidth+4\tabcolsep}` for the width and. of course, no `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|*3{p{.31\linewidth} |}}\hline 
    \textbf{Ernout/Meillet\textsubscript{4}} & \textbf{REW\textsubscript{3}} & 
    \textbf{DÉRom}  \\ \hline 
            apert\={u}ra & ap\u{e}rt\={u}ra & \makecell[l]{*/aper\textquotesingle 
            t-ur-a/\\\hspace{4pt} $\longrightarrow$ I. */aper\textquotesingle t-ur-a/  \\ 
    \hspace{4pt} $\longrightarrow$ II. */oper\textquotesingle t-ur-a/} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr0.93\linewidth+4\tabcolsep}|}{Les issues romanes ont été 
subdivisées selon les deux 
types dont elles relèvent : */aper't-ur-a/ (I.) et */oper't-ur-a/ (II.). I. 
            représente une évolution phonétique régulière de protorom. */aper't-ur-a/ et 
            il existe en italien, romanche, espagnol, asturien, galicien et portugais....  
            }   \\\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tabularx` it should be:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}\hline 
... 
\multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{...}
 ...
\end{tabularx}
```