# How to add a multi-line with multicolumn and tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

I have the following table with `tabularx`, and I want the last cell to be multi-line, as the **Multi-line 1** and **Multi-line 2** marked cells.

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\linespread{1.5} % Set the line-spacing
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| m{0.025\linewidth} | m{0.74\linewidth} | Y |}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{4473c5} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{\color{white} \textbf{Foo}}} & {\color{white} \textbf{Foo BarBaz}} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{b3c6e7} \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Lorem ipsum}} \\  \hline
1 & \textbf{Dolor sit} & 0.5 \\ \hline
2 & \textbf{Multi-line 1:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin feugiat eros et mauris dictum, tempus finibus mauris iaculis. Sed suscipit finibus sem. & 2.5 \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{b3c6e7}
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Consecteur adipiscing}} \\ \hline
3 & \textbf{Multi-line 2:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac metus nec risus euismod varius nec nec turpis. Curabitur efficitur. & 1 \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{b3c6e7}
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Present ac metus}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{This is the cell I want to be also multi-line. } \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Foo}
\label{tab:my-table2}
\end{table}
```

As I have it right now, that last cell does not support multi-line correctly.

- **With short text:**
  [image: short text]
- **With long text:**
  [image: long text]

> How can I make the last cell to behave as the **Multi-line 1** and **Multi-line 2** marked cells.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: you have `\multicolumn{3}{|l|}`  `l` columns are always single line and set natural width.

Comment: Use `multicolumn{3}{|p{\linewidth}|}{This is the cell I want to be also multi-line. }`

Comment: @Alber8295 please see if the answer below suits your requirement

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP did not respond to received answer even after 9 months.

Comment: But it's not off-topic at all @Zarko

Comment: Well, you need nine monts to respond on received answer :-(. it is nice, that you accept it now and by this inform us, that your problem is solved. I will retract my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look now -- I have used some shortcuts for all the various multicolumns being used

For the the last row thanks to  --  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377722/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
    
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf {#1}}}
\newcommand{\md}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf {#1}}}
\newcommand{\me}[1]{\multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep- 
2\arrayrulewidth}|}{#1}}

\linespread{1.5} % Set the line-spacing


    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \def\arraystretch{1}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| m{0.025\linewidth} | m{0.74\linewidth} | Y |}
            \hline
            \rowcolor[HTML]{4473c5} \md{Foo} 
            & {\textbf{Foo BarBaz}}                         \\ \hline
            \rowcolor[HTML]{b3c6e7}\mc{Lorem ipsum}         \\ \hline
            1 
            & \textbf{Dolor sit} 
            & 0.5                                           \\ \hline
            2 
            & \textbf{Multi-line 1:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
           adipiscing elit.     Proin feugiat eros et mauris dictum, tempus finibus 
            mauris iaculis. Sed suscipit finibus sem. 
            & 2.5                                           \\ \hline
            \rowcolor[HTML]{b3c6e7}
            \mc{Present ac metus}                           \\ \hline
            3 
            & \textbf{Multi-line 2:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
           adipiscing elit. Praesent ac metus nec risus euismod varius nec nec turpis. 
            Curabitur efficitur. 
            & 1                                             \\ \hline
            \rowcolor[HTML]{b3c6e7}
            \mc{Present ac metus}                           \\ \hline
            \me{I want a new line I want a new line I want a new line I want a new 
            line I want a new line I want a new line}                           \\ \hline       
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Foo}
        \label{tab:my-table2}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```