# split argument of newcommand that goes into a multicolumn element across multiple lines

Tags: vertical-alignment, line-breaking, tabularx, multicolumn

I have modified the following function coming from a CV template:

```
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabularx}{6in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabularx}\vspace{2pt}}
```

into:

```
\newcommand{\ressubheading2}[5]{
\begin{tabularx}{6in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}\indent \textbf{Report}: \makecell{{#5}}}
\end{tabularx}\vspace{2pt}}
```

to accept an additional input argument. The modified one can be used in this way:

```
\ressubheading2{MyUniversity}{Country }{Course of Studies}{from - to}{Final report}
```

When there are multiple entries of this type in the document, both functions allow to align them. If the string representing the input 5 of is sufficiently short everything work fine. However, if the string is too long, entries are not aligned anymore. I tried to split the last entry with `\newline`:

```
\ressubheading2{MyUniversity}{Country }{Course of Studies}{from - to}{Very, extremely long final report title \newline that misaligns everything}
```

But this does not work.

How can I split the line that goes into a `\multicolumn{}` element of `tabularx`to keep alignment?

**FULL WORKING EXAMPLE**

Here it is an example that shows better what I mean.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}



\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabularx}{6in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabularx}\vspace{2pt}}

\newcommand{\ressubheadingNew}[5]{
\begin{tabularx}{6in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}\indent \textbf{Thesis}: \makecell{{#5}}}
\end{tabularx}\vspace{2pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\Huge MyName} \\
peter@neverland.com & Mobile: 018923123890123890123890 \\
 & \\
\end{tabularx}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%SECTION%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}{Bachelor studies in Flight}{September 2020 - October 2020}{Development of flight}
    \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}{Master studies in Flight}{October 2020 - November 2020}{Development of swimming skills}
        \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}{Postgraduate studies in Flight}{October 2020 - November 2020}{Very long title that should be split across lines but that does not even when using newline}    
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- For the last item in definition of the `\ressubheadingNew` command you use `\makecell` command. It not break its content automatically, so you need to break it manually by inserting of ` \ in appropriate place.
- In definition of the `\ressubheadingNew` you have at `makcell` one pair of the curly braces to much. It should be as follows:

```
\newcommand{\ressubheadingNew}[5]{
\begin{tabularx}{6in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}\indent \textbf{Thesis}:% 
        \makecell[t]{#5}}  % <--- aded [t] and remove one pair of {}
\end{tabularx}\vspace{2pt}}
```

Test with MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % should be loaded last in preamble

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}



\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabularx}{6in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabularx}\vspace{2pt}}

\newcommand{\ressubheadingNew}[5]{
\begin{tabularx}{6in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}\indent \textbf{Thesis}:% 
        \makecell[t]{#5}}
\end{tabularx}\vspace{2pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\Huge MyName} \\
peter@neverland.com & Mobile: 018923123890123890123890 \\
 & \\
\end{tabularx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}{Bachelor studies in Flight}{September 2020 - October 2020}{Development of flight}
    \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}{Master studies in Flight}{October 2020 - November 2020}{Development of swimming skills}
        \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}{Postgraduate studies in Flight}{October 2020 - November 2020}{Very long title that should be split\\ across lines but that does not even\\ when using newline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I was looking for. See my answer taken from another post: it seems to be more appropriate.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi, I only show errors in your command definition and its use. I haven't attention to make new design of your command. But I'm glad, that you find yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to use tables, but just to format a paragraph, e.g. as follows.

```
\newcommand\ressubheadingNew[5]{%
   \par\medskip\noindent
   \textbf{#1}\hfill #2\\
   \textit{#3}\hfill\textit{#4}\\
   \hspace*{4ex}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4ex}{\textbf{Thesis:} #5}%
}
```

The last line illustrates that you can use `\parboxes` to confine text. This approach has also the advantage that it breaks across pages.

[image]

```
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}



\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabularx}{6in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabularx}\vspace{2pt}}

% \newcommand{\ressubheadingNew}[5]{
% \begin{tabularx}{6in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
%         \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
%         \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
%         \multicolumn{2}{l}{\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}\indent \textbf{Thesis}: \makecell{{#5}}}
% \end{tabularx}\vspace{2pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand\ressubheadingNew[5]{%
\par\medskip\noindent
\textbf{#1}\hfill #2\\
\textit{#3}\hfill\textit{#4}\\
\hspace*{4ex}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4ex}{\textbf{Thesis:} #5}%
}


\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\Huge MyName} \\
peter@neverland.com & Mobile: 018923123890123890123890 \\
 & \\
\end{tabularx}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%SECTION%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}{Bachelor studies in Flight}{September 2020 - October 2020}{Development of flight}
    \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}{Master studies in Flight}{October 2020 - November 2020}{Development of swimming skills}
    \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}{Postgraduate studies in Flight}{October 2020 - November 2020}{Very long title that should be split using newline like here\\
    but which also splits automatically if it is long enough and goes on and goes on and goes on and goes on and goes on and goes on and goes on}    
  \ressubheadingNew{University of Neverland}{Neverland}%
  {\parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{This illustrates an emergency if the title of the master programme is really long}}{October 2020 - November 2020}{Development of swimming skills}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works from is taken [from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377722/60344):

```
\newcommand{\ressubheadingNew}[5]{
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
        \multicolumn{2}{{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}}}{\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}\indent \textbf{Thesis}: {#5}}\\
\end{tabularx}\vspace{2pt}}
```